# Uninstall Metasploit problem

Tags: software-uninstall, metasploit

I had serious problems with Metasploit since I installed it, so I want to uninstall it

I did try `/opt/metasploit-4.5.0/`uninstall but it doesn't work

it shows a yes and no .. I choose yes then wait some seconds another window opens for 0.01sec then closes and it types Killed in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had some problems with my Metasploit on 12.10.

I, by mistake of course, deleted my `/opt/metasploit-4.5.0` before I found out it had an uninstaller inside. What I did to reinstall was search my file system for metasploit. Through root terminal (`sudo su`) I went and `rm`ed all of the files. Then I ran the installer with `sudo ./YOUR_DIRECTORY_HERE/metasploit-latest-linux-installel.run`.

To succesfully reinstall Metasploit, be sure to remove ALL of the old Metasploit files in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc0-6.d`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to navigate to the directory `/opt/metasploit-4.5.0`.
Open a terminal window ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `cd /opt/metasploit-4.5.0` .
 Next, run `./uninstall` in your Terminal window. 
A uninstall window should pop up

Comment: this is what I did .. a window poped out with yes or no ,, I chose yes then nothing happened 
/opt/metasploit-4.5.0# ./uninstall
Killed

Comment: Try running it as root: `sudo ./uninstall`

Comment: same problem it types Killed @TravisG.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `./uninstall` with root user.

```
cd /opt/metasploit    
sudo ./uninstall
```

Uninstall wizard will pop up. Best regards.