# How can I uninstall metasploit?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall metasploit problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248959/uninstall-metasploit-problem)

I had serious problems with `metasploit` since I installed it, so I want to uninstall it.

I did try `/opt/metasploit-4.5.0/uninstall` but it doesn't work.
It shows a `yes` and `no`. I choose `yes` and after a few seconds another window opens for 0.01 sec then closes and it types `Killed` in the terminal.

so how do I uninstall it ?

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: You have already asked this question yesterday! [Uninstall metasploit problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248959/uninstall-metasploit-problem) We do not re-ask questions here.

Comment: use "sudo /opt/metasploit/uninstall" (without quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you only would have to `sudo rm -rf /opt/metasploit`.

Be careful with this command since it will recursively (`-r`) and forcefully (`-f`, no questions asked) remove the path that is specified.

Comment: removing it solved my problem, thnx

Comment: Many years later... this still works but on my ubuntu 18.04 system it left links in /usr/bin pointing to /etc/alternatives which had links pointing to the file in /opt/...

Comment: actually it looks as if MSF is installed as a package so you can use apt to rm it